How to solve a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import a local .ipynb library in Jupyter Notebook?
I'm not even sure if I'm asking the right question, so let me provide more context.
I need to use the AutoComet program for research purposes. Since the Issues section on GitHub appears to be inactive, I'm seeking help here.
I cloned the program and installed all the required libraries listed in the 'requirements' section.
The issue arises when executing the AutoComet-Main.ipynb file, which attempts to import the AutoComet_Functions library.  Since this library doesn't seem to be public, I assume it's a local file, specifically an AutoComet_Functions.ipynb file located in the parent directory (please refer to the GitHub link for clarification). The line import AutoComet_Functions as ac throws a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AutoComet_Functions'.
I attempted to modify the line import AutoComet_Functions as ac to from . import AutoComet_Functions as ac, but this results in an ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

Place the notebook AutoComet-Main.ipynb in the same directory as you have AutoComet_Functions.ipynb.
In the notebook AutoComet-Main.ipynb where you are working, make a new cell near the top and put in it %pip install import_ipynb. Run that cell and then restart the kernel and then import AutoComet_Functions as ac will work.
Context:
The code in AutoComet-Main.ipynb starts off:
import import_ipynb
import AutoComet_Functions as ac

The line above import AutoComet_Functions as ac is import import_ipynb. That, or a similar package, is needed to add the ability to import a notebook as a package. (Depending on what package you use to do this the syntax can be different for the actual importing step.)
The current requirements.txt file there in the AutoComet repo doesn't list import_ipynb; however, it should because that is not part of the standard library, and it isn't overly common as it is not very active, as you can see here and from it note being suggested here in answer to 'Package for Importing Jupyter Notebooks as Modules'.
You need that special import package then and the notebook it will import, AutoComet_Functions.ipynb, must be on the path of the kernel environment running AutoComet-Main.ipynb. The easiest way to do that is to put AutoComet_Functions.ipynb alongside the AutoComet-Main.ipynb because that current directory of a running Jupyter .ipynb file always gets added to the path for the active kernel.
Less ideal alternative
If you put the notebook AutoComet-Main.ipynb in the same directory as you have AutoComet_Functions.ipynb, you could replace the two lines I indicated above in AutoComet-Main.ipynb with %run AutoComet_Functions.ipynb. Also then delete importlib.reload(ac). Using %run AutoComet_Functions.ipynb would be an alternative way to bring the functions and methods of AutoComet_Functions.ipynb into the current namespace. That would though need further edits when you want to use the functions and methods from that notebook because they will be in the main namespace instead of under the ac variable like the import statement import AutoComet_Functions as ac would have done. So lines like ac.image_preview(img_filelist, image_rotation, image_fipping, num_images=preview_images) would beed to be edited to image_preview(img_filelist, image_rotation, image_fipping, num_images=preview_images). Depending on how things were done it may be trickier if function/method names overlap because they expect one to be under ac.
The only advantage of this alternative is that %run AutoComet_Functions.ipynb requires no special package because running another notebook in a current namespace is built in by default. In the import way, you need a special package to import a Juptyer notebook file into an actively running Jupyter notebook.

For those still wishing to learn more, additional related explanation/ example in my comments to the answer and current only answer here.


Option that is further afield of what the developers intended: convert the notebook to a .py script
Jupytext is a good tool for converting notebooks to Python scripts. You can just use a command after you install it, see here. (It is easily pip or conda installed.) (There are other options for this conversion. Jupyter has an option to save the notebook to a script in the File menu. Another option is literally just to copy the code into a text file with a .py extension. If you are worried about doing the copying because there are a lot of cells, there is an automated way to collect the code text here using nbformat which comes in any Jupyter installtion.)
However, this conversion is not a blanket applicable approach if the notebook used IPython/Jupyter and magics, and not pure Python. You will need further edits in that case. Additionally, it is not the way the developers intended it to be used and so if the code was still under development it would mean you have more to track and correct later. It will be more enabling going forward to know how to import an .ipynb file into another.

Thanks, but I've made .py file from .ipynb file, as AI recommended, and now it seems to work. However, there is some other unrelated error which I'm trying to solve now.

Yes, I should have put that as an option. (Jupytext is a good tool for this and more to have in your toolbox.) However, it is not a blanket applicable approach if the notebook used IPython/Jupyter and magics, and not pure Python. Additionally, it is not the way the developers intended it to be used and so if the code was still under development it would mean you have more to track and correct later. It will be more enabling going forward to know how to import an .ipynb file into another.

I've added this to my answer so that it may help others contemplating options.

I've tried your first solution before asking (that was the first error and easiest to solve), but still got the error

I'm overwhelmed by errors in this program, I guess I'll just skip it

Sorry to hear that. Is there an alternative? I'm happy to help as this is more in my field of study than a lot of stuff I help with. My profile here has a tiny GitHub icon to the bottom right of my picture. That goes to my GitHub profile where you can see my email. It'd be better to coordinate there.
